# UICollectionViewCell z-position ignored

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am working on a UICollectionView with a custom UICollectionViewLayout. Each cell is a control that can has a vertical, horizontal, and 'cross' handle that can be dragged by the user to adjust the size of the cell.

[image: collection view sketch]

The user is allowed to insert cells anywhere in the collectionView, including between cells. Because the cells can overlap with one another, it is key that the z-position of each cell always be farther back than the cell to its left. However, when a new cell is inserted between two existing cells, the UICollectionView appears to disregard the z-position that is set in the custom UICollectionViewLayout. That is, what appears on screen does not match the z-position in the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes.

When the entire UICollectionView is reloaded all cells are positioned correctly, but this isn't a viable work around because of the visual artifacts it would introduce (flickering, cells moving around and redrawing).

I have seen that others have had similar problems, but most of the solutions provided involve reloading the UICollectionView. Is there a known work around that would ensure that the z-position of every cell is updated and accurate by the time the insertion animation ends?

Pseudocode for the insertion process looks like this:

```
insertionLocation = currentCellLocation + 1;
dataSource.addEntry(insertLocation);
[collectionView invalidateLayout];
[collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPath@[insertLocation]];
[collectionView performBatchUpdates^{/*...*/} 
               completion:^(BOOL finished){/*...*/}];
```

Thank you for your time.